# Comma between the following clauses in AP Style?

Tags: style, punctuation, ap-style

The AP style says that a comma is not needed between two clauses that have the same subject. However, it would become ambiguous if I removed the comma fromt the following:

> When you walk straight down the hall, you will be met with two doors: the first goes upstairs **,** and the second goes to the outside.

Is the comma after *upstairs* required in the AP Style? Is it a clear "YES" or is it subjective? As a side note, is the use of the **colon** okay according to the AP Style?

Comment: IMHO, your question is flawed.  (1) The clauses  “the first goes upstairs” and  “the second goes outside” do not have  the same subject.  *First* is the subject of the first, and *second* of the second.  (2) Either or both of the commas in the example can be removed without introducing any ambiguity.

Comment: @jwpat7: What about the *colon*? Is colon at all allowed in the AP Style?

Comment: I don't have a copy of AP stylebook but gather from [apvschicago.com](http://www.apvschicago.com/2011/04/capitalization-after-colons.html) that AP has some rules allowing use of colons.

Answer (score 1):

I have the 2011 edition of the AP Stylebook, which gives the following as correct examples:

> He promised this: The company will make good all the losses.
>
> There were three considerations: expense, time, and feasibility.

Yours seems to fit the first example, so as an independent clause it would take a capital letter after the colon.

I would use both commas for absolute clarity.

Comment: Is the capital T in the first sentence a typo or out of the stylebook?

Comment: @DavidGiven No, it's in the AP stylebook. I happen to disagree — I don't think that the independent clause after the colon should take a capital letter — but the OP was asking about AP style. I flagged it in my first line after the blockquote.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's odd too... thanks for the clarification.